# ¿Excluir una lista de Strings en una tabla en C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Hola amigo tengo un problema con una tabla tengo un campo llamado nombres dentro de esta tabla y tengo una list de nombres la cual quiero excluir de la tabla basado en el campo nombre. 
Tengo lo siguiente pero no me resulta.

```
var DataRows = Tabla.AsEnumerable().Where(item => item["Nombre"].ToString().Distinct().Where(nombre=> ListaNombres.ForEach()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías consultar si en la lista de string existe en tu elemento item, con `Any()` , en este caso agregamos un `NOT`, lo cual nos devolvería que si el item existe no lo agrega

```
   var DataRows = Tabla.AsEnumerable().Where(
                    item => !ListaNombres.Any(n => n == item["Nombre"].ToString()));
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, funciona perfecto. Gracias

Comment: Perfecto y debe marcar esto como la respuesta ya que respondió su pregunta.Saludos